# Mongodb on openshift gear local or mongolab?

Tags: mongodb, openshift, mlab

For a web app that will experience far more reads than writes, is it faster to use mongodb locally (on seperate openshift gear) or to use a hosting provider like mongolab. 
I'm aware of the benefits of using mongolab and would like to use but not if it slows down the app.

Has anybody any experience or information comparing the two in regards to speed of reads.
Any info would be great. Thanks

Comment: are you using the OpenShift PaaS? if so, that's hosted on AWS. MongoLab plans are provisioned directly in the cloud provider of your choice (in this case AWS) and is very fast as it stays within the same datacenter. you can email us at support@mongolab.com if you have any more questions